# Multer: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined

Tags: node.js, file, express, input, multer

I am compeletely new to multer package. Even to nodejs :). And I am building NBA app to master my fresh knowledges. And I copied multer package example and modified some details to fit my code. But I got this error. And I think I gave enough (or even too many unnecessary elements). Please help me get through this one.

**Here is my express code:**

```
app.post("/admin/add/team", upload.single('file'), function(req, res){
        var file = __dirname + '/public/img/' + req.file.filename + '.svg';
        fs.rename(req.file.path, file, function(err){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send(500);
            } else {
                var newTeam = {
                    win: 0,
                    lose: 0,
                    teamName: req.body.teamName,
                    fullName: req.body.teamNameFull,
                    img: '/img/' + req.file.filename + '.svg'
                };
                Team.create(newTeam);
                res.redirect("/admin/add/team");
            }
        });
    });
```

**And here is my form:**

```
<div style="width: 30%" class="container">
  <form action="/admin/add/team" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="team-full-name">Team name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="team-full-name" placeholder="Houston Rockets" name="teamNameFull">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="team-name-to-display">Team name to display</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="team-name-to-display" placeholder="HOU" name="teamName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="team-img">Team imageг</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="team-img" name="file">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**And here is the error :**

```
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined**
    at C:\Users\lamborari\Desktop\mnba\app.js:171:50
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\lamborari\Desktop\mnba\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\lamborari\Desktop\mnba\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lamborari\Desktop\mnba\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:53:37)
    at listener (C:\Users\lamborari\Desktop\mnba\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:169:15)
    at onFinish (C:\Users\lamborari\Desktop\mnba\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:100:5)
    at callback (C:\Users\lamborari\Desktop\mnba\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:55:10)
    at IncomingMessage.onevent (C:\Users\lamborari\Desktop\mnba\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:93:5)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
```

Comment: have you declare upload variable with file destination

Comment: What does your multer config look like?

Comment: What do you see in the Network section of your browser's dev tools? Check that the file is being included as expected in the request.